# Why won't this conditional display both options?

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

I can't figure out why my code will only output one result option.

Example: if I put == between choose and artists, the output is the "else" statement even if I enter a band in the array into the prompt. If it's = it only outputs the if statement.

Here's the code:

```js
let artists = ["Arctic Monkeys",
                "The Black Keys",
                "Ghost",
                "Boston",
                "alt-J",
                "Fitz and the Tantrums",
                "Daft Punk",
                "Coldplay",
                "The Killers"];
let choose = prompt("What is your favorite band?");

if (choose == artists){
    alert("That's one of my favorites, too! Band Buddies!!");
} else {
    alert("Sorry, not a favorite of mine.");
}
```

I can't work out what to change since it knows the two options in the conditionals.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The `prompt()` function returns one string. You have an *array* of strings, so that one string will *never* be `==` to the array. You have to write code to determine whether the string is in the array.

Comment: And `=` "works" because it's not comparing; it's an assignment operator.

Comment: That makes sense! Using array.include() solved the problem. I wasn't sure if because the array is a list of string variables it aligns with a string, so this is great to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompt returns a string, but you are comparing it to an array.

There are many solutions to this, a simple solution is to use `array.includes(string)`.

Includes will search the array for the string that you pass to it.

```js
let artists = ["Arctic Monkeys", "The Black Keys", "Ghost", "Boston", "alt-J", "Fitz and the Tantrums", "Daft Punk", "Coldplay", "The Killers"];
let choose = prompt("What is your favorite band?");

if (artists.includes(choose)) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "That's one of my favorites, too! Band Buddies!!";
} else {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Sorry, not a favorite of mine.";
}
```

```html
<div id="output"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you're not accesing to the values of the array.

With your comparison "if(choose == artists)", you're comparing a string (choose variable) and an array (artists).

To check if the array has the value written by the user you can use:

```
if( artists.includes(variable) ) {
   ... your code
} else {
   ...
}
```

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

This solution also uses [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to compare strings, but with the added advice that you should handle user input differently. `.includes()` is case-sensitive so should the user input "the killers", your result would be `false`. In the example below, [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) is used on the "artists" array as well as the user input "choose".

```js
let artists = ["Arctic Monkeys",
  "The Black Keys",
  "Ghost",
  "Boston",
  "alt-J",
  "Fitz and the Tantrums",
  "Daft Punk",
  "Coldplay",
  "The Killers"
];

/* Convert all strings to lower case. Or ensure that your array already has 
lower case strings beforehand. */
artists = artists.map(band => band.toLowerCase());

let choose = prompt("What is your favorite band?");

/* Reference "output" once, to cut down on unnecessary repetition. */
const output = document.getElementById("output");

/* .includes() will return true if the array has a match. Make sure to convert 
the user input "choose" to lower case. */
if (artists.includes(choose.toLowerCase())) {
  output.innerHTML =
    "That's one of my favorites, too! Band Buddies!!";
} else {
  output.innerHTML =
    "Sorry, not a favorite of mine.";
}
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```